# SQL Query to generate amount of tickets per status per day in JIRA

Tags: database, postgresql, jira, reporting

I'm currently trying to generate a report for the amount of tickets each status had on any given day. So far, I can generate this report/table for a single project on a single given day.

I'd like to generate a table that has all days with the amounts of tickets in each status.

I'm using PostgreSQL and this is the query so far (based on their own documentation):

```
SELECT count(*), STEP.STEP_ID
 FROM (SELECT STEP_ID, ENTRY_ID
 FROM OS_CURRENTSTEP
 WHERE OS_CURRENTSTEP.START_DATE < '04.07.2017'
UNION SELECT STEP_ID, ENTRY_ID
 FROM OS_HISTORYSTEP
 WHERE OS_HISTORYSTEP.START_DATE < '04.07.2017'
 AND OS_HISTORYSTEP.FINISH_DATE > '04.07.2017' ) As STEP,
(SELECT changeitem.OLDVALUE::numeric AS VAL, changegroup.ISSUEID AS ISSID
 FROM changegroup, changeitem
 WHERE changeitem.FIELD = 'status'
 AND changeitem.GROUPID = changegroup.ID
UNION SELECT jiraissue.WORKFLOW_ID AS VAL, jiraissue.id as ISSID
 FROM jiraissue) As VALID,
jiraissue as JI
WHERE STEP.ENTRY_ID = VALID.VAL
AND VALID.ISSID = JI.id
AND JI.project = <'PROJECT ID HERE'>
Group By STEP.STEP_ID
```

Comment: If we will not give Date condition in where clause WHERE OS_CURRENTSTEP.START_DATE < '04.07.2017'


 WHERE OS_HISTORYSTEP.START_DATE < '04.07.2017'
 AND OS_HISTORYSTEP.FINISH_DATE > '04.07.2017' ) then it will return for all dates for given project

Comment: The query you are using is correct as per given in documentation https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA040/Example+SQL+queries+for+JIRA